# Intellij Spring: NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'accountDAO' available

Tags: spring

This is driving me nuts. I have the following files, it is a very simple setup.

```
public class MainApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    //read the spring config java class
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("Config.class");

    //System.out.println("Bean names: " + Arrays.toString(context.getBeanNamesForType(AccountDAO.class)));

    //get the bean from spring container
    AccountDAO accountDAO = context.getBean("accountDAO", AccountDAO.class);

    //call the business method
    accountDAO.addAccount();

    //close the spring context
    context.close();
  }
}

Config.java:

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.aop")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class Config {
}

LoggingAspectDemo.java:

@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspectDemo {

    //this is where we add all our related advices for the logging

    //let's start with an @Before advice
    @Before("execution(public void addAccount())")
    public void beforeAddAccountAdvice() {
        System.out.println("\n=======>>>> Executing @Before advice on method addAccount() <<<<========");
    }
}



AccountDAO.java

@Component
public class AccountDAO {
    public void addAccount() {
        System.out.println(getClass() + ": Doing my Db work: Adding an account");
    }
}
```

Everytime I run the MainApp.java, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'accountDAO' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
```

All the files are under "com.aop" package so @ComponentScan should be scanning all the components. It looks simple enough but I can't get my hands around the problem, can anyone help me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're invoking the constructor of `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` with `"Config.class"` as String argument, but this constructor is actually for invoking with [base packages](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.html#AnnotationConfigApplicationContext-java.lang.String...-) i.e. the argument must be a package name.

Since you want to use it with the Configuration class, use the constructor [which accepts Class instance](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.html#AnnotationConfigApplicationContext-java.lang.Class...-) instead i.e.

`AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);`

Comment: Vasan, thank you. That solved my issue. I should have paid more attention to that.